# How do I access the children of the clicked element using REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a very simple app, using REACT, that calls an API and brings a random phrase.
Whenever I click on the phrase I want to be able to access the clicked word, but I couldn't figure how to do it (I read lots if similar posts but even with that I could not make it work).

This is the code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { phrase: [] };
  }

  handlerApi = async () => {
    const api_call = await fetch(
      "https://api.whatdoestrumpthink.com/api/v1/quotes/random"
    );
    const data = await api_call.json();
    const phrase_array = data.message.split(" ");
    this.setState({ phrase: phrase_array });
  };
  handlerWordClicked = (word) => {
    console.log(word);
  };

  render() {
    let phrase = this.state.phrase.map((word) => word + " ");
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handlerApi}>Call api</button>
          <div>
            {" "}
            <p onClick={(e) => this.handlerWordClicked(e.target)}>{phrase}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each word from the state into a `<span>`, and attach a listener to each `<span>`:

```
{
  this.state.phrase.map(word => (
    <span onClick={() => { console.log(word); }}>{word + ' '}</span>
  ))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
<script type='text/jsx'>
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { phrase: [] };
  }

  handlerApi = async () => {
    const api_call = await fetch(
      "https://api.whatdoestrumpthink.com/api/v1/quotes/random"
    );
    const data = await api_call.json();
    const phrase_array = data.message.split(" ");
    this.setState({ phrase: phrase_array });
  };
  handlerWordClicked = (word) => {
    console.log(word);
  };

  render() {
    let phrase = this.state.phrase.map((word) => word + " ");
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handlerApi}>Call api</button>
          <div>
            {" "}
            <p>
              {
                this.state.phrase.map(word => (
                  <span onClick={() => { console.log(word); }}>{word + ' '}</span>
                ))
              }
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a reference to an `HTMLParagraphElement` DOM object, so just access its `innerHTML` attribute.

```
handlerWordClicked = (e) => {
  console.log(e.innerHTML);
};
```

But if you want to do this in a more React way, just store and retrieve the phrase as a string in the component's state.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { phrase: '' };
  }

  handlerApi = async () => {
    const api_call = await fetch(
      "https://api.whatdoestrumpthink.com/api/v1/quotes/random"
    );
    const data = await api_call.json();
    this.setState({ phrase: data.message });
  };

  handlerWordClicked = () => {
    console.log(this.state.phrase);
  };

  render() {
    const { phrase } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handlerApi}>Call api</button>
          <div>
            {" "}
            <p onClick={(e) => this.handlerWordClicked(e.target)}>{phrase}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Neither of those approaches allows the clicked **word** to be used by the script, it'll just give a reference to the whole paragraph

Comment: Ah, sorry. You wanted the individual word... and I see @CertainPerformance already gave you an answer.